# How to Remove Parameters coming in ETEXT in BI Publisher

Tags: xml, oracle, bi-publisher, edi

i am using delimiter based template to generate CSV file

all output is fine except the parameters

which are showing up even without adding them explicitly in the ETEXT

how can i disable these parameters

following is the output

**P_DATE_FROM,P_DATE,P_BU,ID,**LOCALE,NAME,JOB_CODE,JOB_FAMILY,JOB_ROLE1,ROLE_IS_REQUIRED1
**2022-01-01T04:00:00.000+04:00,2024-01-01T04:00:00.000+04:00,,**1,en_US,"Vice President - Investment Management",300000003295735,TESLA,"Vice President - Investment Management",TRUE

this is the sample XML

<DATA_DS>**<P_DATE_FROM>2023-01-01T04:00:00.000+04:00</P_DATE_FROM><P_DATE>2023-03-22T04:00:00.000+04:00</P_DATE><P_BU/>**
<G_1>
1en_USVice President - Investment Management<JOB_CODE>300000003295735</JOB_CODE><JOB_FAMILY>TESLA</JOB_FAMILY><JOB_ROLE1>Vice President - Investment Management</JOB_ROLE1><ROLE_IS_REQUIRED1>TRUE</ROLE_IS_REQUIRED1>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>

these are the EDI Template instructions

```
Format Setup:

Hint: Define formatting options…
<TEMPLATE TYPE> DELIMITER_BASED
<OUTPUT CHARACTER SET>  iso-8859-1
<NEW RECORD CHARACTER>  Carriage Return

Format Data Records :

Hint: Define Data Layout
<LEVEL> DATA_DS


<LEVEL> G_1
<MAXIMUM LENGTH>    <FORMAT>    <DATA>  <COMMENTS>
<NEW RECORD>    
15  Alpha   ID  REFERENCE NUMBER
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NAME    NAME
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   DOMAIN  DOMAIN
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Number  JOB_ROLE    JOB_ROLE
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   JOB_CODE    JOB_CODE
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
35  Alpha   MIN_SALARY  MIN_SALARY
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
35  Alpha   MAX_SALARY  MAX_SALARY
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
23  Alpha   SALARY_CURRENCY SALARY_CURRENCY
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
35  Alpha   JOB_FAMILY  JOB_FAMILY
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
11  Alpha   START_DATE  START_DATE
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
11  Alpha   END_DATE    END_DATE
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   STATUS  STATUS
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   IS_CRITICAL IS_CRITICAL
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   KEY_RESPONSIBILITIES    KEY_RESPONSIBILITIES
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   LOCALE  LOCALE
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NEXT_CARR_STEP1 NEXT_CARR_STEP1
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NEXT_CARR_STEP2 NEXT_CARR_STEP2
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NEXT_CARR_STEP3 NEXT_CARR_STEP3
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NEXT_CARR_STEP4 NEXT_CARR_STEP4
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   NEXT_CARR_STEP5 NEXT_CARR_STEP5
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   JOB_ROLE1   JOB_ROLE1
1   Alpha   ‘;’ 
240 Alpha   ROLE_IS_REQUIRED1   ROLE_IS_REQUIRED1
<END LEVEL> G_1
<END LEVEL> DATA_DS
```

grateful for your time and effort to help

regards
AR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Disable "Include Parameter Tags" in BI Publisher Data Model Properties as in the Snapshot below and that will solve this issue :)]

Disable "Include Parameter Tags" in BI Publisher Data Model Properties as in the Snapshot below and that will solve this issue