# How can I not display headers in CSV format output of BIP report?

Tags: bi-publisher

My requirement is to have output of BIP report in .CSV format but it should display only data and no headers.
I tried using an eText template, but I am still getting header. How can I achieve this?

Attached is the sample output as well as the eText template.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ao5HE.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7lUZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have preferences set to display incoming parameters.

Check this:
[How to Remove Parameters coming in ETEXT in BI Publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829642/how-to-remove-parameters-coming-in-etext-in-bi-publisher)